# How to fix "npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded" in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install, google-cloud-build

My latest Google Cloud Builds are failing with the following error:

```
Step 3/16 : RUN npm i
 ---> Running in 9b3b8df05c12
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.0.2 -> 7.0.3
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.0.3>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.0.3` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The last successful build was on October 17th. Since then, I have only made one commit which changed some typescript. Nothing in the dockerfile or NPM dependencies has changed.

The relevant section of the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node AS minifier
COPY MyProject/Client .
RUN npm i
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli rollup
RUN grunt release
```

It looks like the issue is specifically with the `RUN npm i` command. Is this a bug? Is there anything I can do to fix it? I did retry the build, but encountered the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue caused due to the latest release of npm i.e. v7.0.3. There are multiple alternatives to this:

- You can change the base image to `node:15.0.0` or `node:15.0.0-slim`
- Alternatively using `yarn` instead of npm can also fix this issue
- Run `npm cache clean --force` before `npm i` in your Dockerfile

I'd recommend changing the base image.

Comment: Thank you! Specifying an older node image resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the root problem is a slow internet connection to the npm registry. After I changed to another npm registry, the problem was never triggered.